# Spring mvc: what is the params separator

Tags: spring-mvc, portlet

I was wondering what the seperator is for params (`@ActionMapping(params ="...");`)

I'd like to place a back button inside a form which already has a next button, and I've read in the docs 
that I can do: `myParam!=myValue` to ignore things so I would like to do sonething like:

```
@ActionMapping(params="myAction=registerUser**SEPARATOR**nextParam!=previous"){}

@ActionMapping(params="nextParam=previous"){}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`params` is an array:

```
@ActionMapping(params = {"myAction=registerUser", "nextParam!=previous"})
```